# textbox with huge data in c# windows form

Tags: c#, textbox

when I added huge data to textbox ,I cannot edit that textbox by keyboard (can cut but cannot paste , cannot type) .What happened? And What should I do?

Any advice please.

For example , after this code, the textbox go abnormal.

```
        String test="";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            test += i.ToString() + "\r\n";
        }

        textBox1.Text = test;
        return;
```

Comment: you should use a textarea for large amount of text

Comment: Use `textBox1.AppendText()` method instead of `immutable` string object.

Comment: "Any advice please."  Don't display ridiculous amounts of data for the user?  What is your **real** problem that you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As string object is immutable, This simply means that once created, strings cannot be modified (), and the methods that apparently modify a string, really return a new object with the desired value.

Please use StringBuider instaed of string for manupulations.

Please refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406046/Why-strings-are-immutable-and-what-are-the-implica)

Thanks,